# cutting relevant portions of a file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I want to cut some portions of binary file starting from a particular pattern and ending at a particular pattern.How do I do that in linux using bash.Can this be done using sed or awk?

I have a file like given below.

> bd=0x422e90e0ff4abc00
>   pad=0x82 offset=0x05
>   dst=00:0d:bc:03:6d:80 src=00:50:a2:df:e8:1c
>   etype=0x0800
>   ip: version=4 headerwords=5 tos=32 length=142
>   ip: id=201 flags=0x2 fragmentoffset=0
>   ip: ttl=117 protocol=6 checksum=0x0000
>   ip: sourceaddress=36.190.253.236
>   ip: destinaddress=125.182.162.162
>   bd=0x422e90e0ff61f000
>   pad=0x92 offset=0x19
>   dst=00:50:a2:df:e8:1c src=00:0d:bc:03:6d:80
>   etype=0x0800
>   ip: version=4 headerwords=5 tos=0 length=40
>   ip: id=11084 flags=0x2 fragmentoffset=0
>   ip: ttl=62 protocol=6 checksum=0x0000
>   ip: sourceaddress=125.182.162.162
>   ip: destinaddress=36.190.253.236
>   bd=0x422e90e0ff6bb900
>   pad=0xb8 offset=0x06
>   dst=00:50:a2:df:e8:1c src=00:0d:bc:03:6d:80
>   etype=0x0800
>   ip: version=4 headerwords=5 tos=0 length=40
>   ip: id=15720 flags=0x2 fragmentoffset=0
>   ip: ttl=62 protocol=6 checksum=0x0000
>   ip: sourceaddress=125.182.162.162
>   ip: destinaddress=36.190.253.236
>   bd=0x422e90e0ffbe9a00
>   pad=0xbb offset=0xc5
>   dst=00:50:a2:df:e8:1c src=00:0d:bc:03:6d:80
>   etype=0x0800
>   ip: version=4 headerwords=5 tos=0 length=186
>   ip: id=15722 flags=0x2 fragmentoffset=0
>   ip: ttl=62 protocol=6 checksum=0x0000
>   ip: sourceaddress=125.182.162.162
>   ip: destinaddress=36.190.253.236

I need to cut this file from bd=0x422e90e0ff61f000 to bd=0x422e90e0ffbe9a00.Can this be done using sed or awk.

Comment: Yes, but you've provided no information to use in order to formulate an answer. "Cut", because of the command by the same name, might imply that you're talking vertically, i.e. to remove columns. AWK and `sed` can easily do this. However, AWK and `sed` are also very good at removing (or passing through) selected lines (a horizontal cut as it were). I'm voting to close this as not a real question and recommend that you read [How to Ask](http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask) very thoroughly.

Comment: This sounds like a promising tool for binary files: http://bbe-.sourceforge.net/bbe.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?  (I have your block of text sitting in a file `foo.txt`)

```
$ cat foo.awk
BEGIN {
  RS = "bd=[a-fx0-9]* ";
  FS = "";
}

{
  print $0;
}

$ awk -f foo.awk foo.txt

pad=0x82 offset=0x05 dst=00:0d:bc:03:6d:80 src=00:50:a2:df:e8:1c etype=0x0800 ip: version=4 headerwords=5 tos=32 length=142 ip: id=201 flags=0x2 fragmentoffset=0 ip: ttl=117 protocol=6 checksum=0x0000 ip: sourceaddress=36.190.253.236 ip: destinaddress=125.182.162.162
pad=0x92 offset=0x19 dst=00:50:a2:df:e8:1c src=00:0d:bc:03:6d:80 etype=0x0800 ip: version=4 headerwords=5 tos=0 length=40 ip: id=11084 flags=0x2 fragmentoffset=0 ip: ttl=62 protocol=6 checksum=0x0000 ip: sourceaddress=125.182.162.162 ip: destinaddress=36.190.253.236
pad=0xb8 offset=0x06 dst=00:50:a2:df:e8:1c src=00:0d:bc:03:6d:80 etype=0x0800 ip: version=4 headerwords=5 tos=0 length=40 ip: id=15720 flags=0x2 fragmentoffset=0 ip: ttl=62 protocol=6 checksum=0x0000 ip: sourceaddress=125.182.162.162 ip: destinaddress=36.190.253.236
pad=0xbb offset=0xc5 dst=00:50:a2:df:e8:1c src=00:0d:bc:03:6d:80 etype=0x0800 ip: version=4 headerwords=5 tos=0 length=186 ip: id=15722 flags=0x2 fragmentoffset=0 ip: ttl=62 protocol=6 checksum=0x0000 ip: sourceaddress=125.182.162.162 ip: destinaddress=36.190.253.236
```

So, basically: change the field separator to null, and change the record separator to that "bd=" pattern, and print everything in the record.